# React Native - Position child view above parent's view sibling

Tags: react-native

I build a textinput like facebook's mentions. After typing # you get a list with different hashtags. I have two of them on one site, one for the title and one for the text. 
The problem is, that the hashtag-list from the title is displayed below the text of the content. See Screenshot for that:
[The list of hashtags is behind the lorem ipsum content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3s3VW.png)

I tried using the zIndex but it does not have any effect here. 
The hierachie is as follows:

View:

-- MentionsText Title

--- #List for Title

-- MentionsText Content

--- #List for Content

As you can see, the content is below the title in the hierachy. That positions it correctly on the screen, but displayes itself above the list of the title. Is there any way of accomplishing it with a smooth solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that contains wrapping both textinput in one view, changing the order (content first, then title) and then setting flexDirection of the view to 'column-reverse'. That way the title is again on top and the z-index is now correctly set too. Just doesnt seem very nice, maybe someone got a tip to improve it. The code is the following (note that the MentionsTextInput contains the List as a child):

```
 <View style={{flexDirection:'column-reverse'}}> //The newly added view
                        <MentionsTextInput //The content of the page
                            style={styles.inputContent}
                            placeholder={I18n.t("descriptionInput")}
                            value={this.state.description}/>

                        <MentionsTextInput //The title
                            style={styles.inputTitle}
                            placeholder={I18n.t("noteTitle")}
                            value={this.state.title}/>
 </View>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your blocs into views independently, don't use absolute position.

Btw if your list can grow without limit you may need a `ScrollView` or `FlatList`.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. I tried moving the views in seperate Views but it doesn't change anything. I use the standart positioning, so everthing aligns under each other which is nice. However, this also seem to be causing the bug (content is in the code below title and so it is rendered later).

Comment: I found a quite nasty solution in my eyes, but it seems to work. I'll post code in an separate answer.